# Factors affecting Refractive index

Tags: optics, visible-light, temperature, water, refraction

I have a doubt  that with increase in temperature the refractive index is decreasing but refractive index of ice is lower than water????

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refractive_index#Density), it is a rule of thumb that index of refraction increases with density. That is, light travels slower in more dense substances. The same article gives a microscopic explanation of the reason [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refractive_index#Density). In brief, atoms interact with light, slowing it. More atoms -> more slowing.

Unlike most substances, solid ice is less dense than liquid water.